# Belongs to Relationship in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So i have the following form to create a new restaurant instance. In my design every restaurant belongs to a city. In the form below I created a a dropdown to give the user to flexibility to chose the city of the restaurant but now I want to change that. The only way to add a restaurant in my application is through the page of a city. So once the user is in that city's page its pretty obvious that he wants to add a restaurant to that city, not to any other one. So how do i modify this so that the new restaurant belongs to the city that the user wants to add the restaurant to. In other words if the user clicked add new restaurant button in the New York City page I want this form to be only able to add a new restaurant to new york city.

```
<%= form_for(@restaurant) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :adress %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :adress %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :review %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :review %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390029/rails-models-design-decision/16390205#16390029?

Comment: yepp deleting this as soon as the other one is resolved, can you have a look at it again thanks, i changed my question a bit

Answer (score 0):

Add a `hidden_field` tag, pass the city id as a URL param, populate the hidden field using `params[:id]`.